# Can not run sample R/dashDB script "Server Memory Usage"

Tags: dashdb

Tried to run the server memory usage sample script as advised in the Youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtEfRv_xuOA.

1. Clicked on "Analytics"
2. Clicked on "R Scripts"
3. Clicked on "Server Memory Usage"

I don't get any plot, only console output:

```
Loading required package: RODBC, ibmdbR ...

Attaching package: ‘arules’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    %in%, write 

Loading required package: rpart, rpart.plot ...

Error in ida.data.frame("SAMPLES.SHOWCASE_SYSUSAGE") : 

  Table SAMPLES.SHOWCASE_SYSUSAGE does not exist

Execution halted
Warning message:
closing unused RODBC handle 1 

mv: cannot stat `/mnt/blumeta0/home/dash8199//.psovPazrgsoFeO6urEt07ZL/1482955766453/output/*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: You may want to explain briefly what you are doing and include relevant parts of the script as part of your question, instead of linking to some Youtube video.

Comment: I'm a newbie, looking how to use R and dashDB, libraries, how to visualise/plot. However, I don't have a script so far, just wanted to follow the instructions in the video to learn more about the topic: Analytics > In-Database Analytics > Server Memory Usage

Comment: The fact that you are a newbie and your general goals are irrelevant. As it stands now, your question requires that someone 1) watch some sort of a Youtube movie, 2) follow instructions in that movie in the hope of reproducing your error, 3) understanding the error background, and 4) explaining it to you. Finding such a person is not very likely. You will have better chances for a meaningful answer if you provide as much information as possible in your question, including steps to reproduce, expected and actual results, and whatever troubleshooting you have conducted. Good luck.

Comment: the video is very short, it's only 3 steps which I now added to the problem description. When I re-ran the steps some more information came up. Looks like a required table is not available.

Answer (score 0):

that's concerning. I assume you are using a dashDB entry plan instance in Bluemix. I can't reproduce it with my instances there. But there are multiple physical servers driving the dashDB entry plan instances overall. Which dashDB server are you using? Just provide the URL of the dashDB web console that you get when you launch dashDB. Do you see the table SHOWCASE_SYSUSAGE in schema SAMPLES at all in TABLES page in the web console?